# Server reboot needed for apache2 to take changes

Tags: apache-http-server

I'm having a problem with Apache2 on my multi-domain server.
Every time I add a new vhost for my configuration to take effect i need to reboot my server.
The strange thing is when i enter the domain sometimes it goes to the correct page other times goes to the default page of the server.

I have already checked my config files and they all seem ok. 
I have been cleaning my sites-enabled to only have the ones active.

This is just to demonstrate my cycle for creating a new page.
New Vhost > a2ensite NewVhost (after this sudo service apache2 reload (or) restart) > Reboot > Letsencrypt Cert > Reboot > All good.

Anyone got any ideas for this problem?

Comment: How about reloading/restarting Apache with `service apache2 reload` or `service apache2 restart` instead of rebooting? I guess you only need to reload the server to read the new configuration, but if you want to be on the safe side, then restarting is still easier than rebooting.

Comment: @Freddy restarting the service the configs don't take effect. I do the a2ensite newvhost.conf and sudo service apache2 reload / restart and when i try to check the site sometimes it shows other times it goes to the default vhost configuration site.

Comment: Then that's either a problem with a broken configuration (always check with `apachectl configtest` before reloading/restarting) or a network / DNS problem or maybe browser cache foo. If the problem occurs, make sure you check the access / error logs. Personally, I never had to reboot a server to enable a new site.

Comment: All syntax is Ok all vhosts are created equally, its not DNS problem. I have 6 more servers and all work properly with just the service restart / reload

Comment: When you say default page, do you mean the apache default welcome page? Can you check for a welcome.conf in any config directories (conf.d etc) and rename/remove [see this](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-disable-the-default-apache-welcome-page-in-centos-rhel-7/)

Comment: @Smock No, I believe he means the default vhost. That's when the first defined vhost is used as default if no `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` matches (name based vhosts). So the new vhost sometimes behaves as if it was missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need to reboot the whole server, just use

```
service apache2 reload
```

or even

```
service apache2 restart
```

or similar depending on the OS you are using.

Comment: i updated the post i do this command after the a2ensite newvhost.conf and it doesn't take effect. Sometimes it goes to the correct site others it goes to the default page.

Comment: maybe your apache is launched twice? try to **service apache2 stop** and look at **ps ax | grep apache**

Comment: I did stop the apache2 and the ps ax | grep "apache" still has 3 lines of "/usr/sbin/apache2 -k start" active and one "grep --color=auto apache" does this mean i have 3 apache2 services still running after stop ?

Comment: yep. try to kill them instead of machine rebooting. Ps. if your apache is default prefork, it creates more than one instance of itself, this is ok. But not ok it is not killing them on service stop.